# Number sequence labyrinth

Tags: number-sequence, mazes

> Can you find the way out of the labyrinth ?

**Rules:**

> Each color you pass is a number (or character) sequence, you have to note the solution of this sequence. 
>   When you're out of the maze, your answers will be checked. If only one answer is false you lose.
>
> **You start on the red cell**.
>
> **Both green cells are possible outputs**.

[image]

GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -1,5,11,17 (a[i+1] = a[i]+6)
>  ab,aabb,aaabbb (aaaabbbb, aaaaabbbbb...)
>  1,10,110,1101,11011 (OP explained in comment)
>  1234,408,320,60 (12*34 = 408, 40*8 = 320, 3*20 = 60)
>  -35,5,50,100 (a[i+1] = a[i] + (40 + 5 * i))
>  [image]

Comment: Nice! For the last one I expected 2 but your solution is also correct.

Comment: how does the 1,10,... sequence work?

Comment: $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ has to be given. $n = 3$ is the number $n = 1$, $n = 2$ you read these two numbers without the comma. So you get $110$. Then you make this for each $n$ and every time you do this, you add one digit.